# std::min vs ternary gcc auto vectorization with #pragma GCC optimize ("O3")

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization, auto-vectorization

I know that "why is my compiler doing this" aren't the best type of questions, but this one is really bizarre to me and I'm thoroughly confused.

I had thought that `std::min()` was the same as the handwritten ternary (with maybe some compile time template stuff), and it seems to compile down into the same operation when used normally. However, when trying to make a "min and sum" loop autovectorize they don't seem to be the same, and I would love if someone could help me figure out why. Here is a small example code that produces the issue:

```
#pragma GCC target ("avx2")
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

#define N (1<<20)
char a[N], b[N];

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        a[i] = rand()%100;
        b[i] = rand()%100;
    }

    int ans = 0;
    #pragma GCC ivdep
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        //ans += std::min(a[i], b[i]);
        ans += a[i]>b[i] ? a[i] : b[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", ans);
}
```

I compile this on `gcc 9.3.0`, with the compilation command `g++ -o test test.cpp -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed -fopt-info-vec-optimized -funsafe-math-optimizations`.

And the code above as is debugs during compilation as:

```
test.cpp:19:17: optimized: loop vectorized using 32 byte vectors
```

In contrast, if I comment the ternary and uncomment the `std::min`, I get this:

```
test.cpp:19:17: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cpp:20:35: missed: statement clobbers memory: _9 = std::min<char> (_8, _7);
```

So `std::min()` seems to be doing something unusual that prevents gcc from understanding that it is just a min operation. Is this something that is caused by the standard? Or is it an implementation failure? Or is there some compile flag that would make this work?

Comment: It appears that adding an optimization level of `-O1` or higher [achieves the vectorization](https://godbolt.org/z/EYeTe4EfW).  I suspect it's a matter of function inlining.

Comment: @MarekR this isn't premature optimization, on my computer it sped up by >2x. Your compiler explorer link I think doesn't have the vectorization flags, because the asm output has no vectorization instructions (e.g. `vpaddd` etc)

Comment: Yeah, none of those optimization options actually does anything unless you use `-O`.  In particular, without `-O` the compiler won't inline `std::min`, so for all it knows it might modify the globals `a,b`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/dnGb61PYT

Comment: I have the `optimze("O3")` pragma at the top of my code? Do i just not understand how that works?

Comment: And I in compiler options.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question.  At a quick reading, `#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")` is equivalent to specifying `__attribute__((optimize("O3")))` on every function.  But I might guess that this does not allow for interprocedural optimizations like inlining, and so it may not be equivalent to using `-O3` on the command line.  Anyway, this shows that in practice they are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @NateEldredge ah wow that's embarrassing, so that pragma is not the same as normal `-O3`. The more you know i guess. If you make that an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider using portable OpenMP SIMD directives rather than compiler specific ivdep, especially if your goal is vectorization (eg. SIMD functions and `#pragma omp simd`). Note that GCC is very sensitive to the operator in the ternary (`(a>b)?c:d` can surprizingly give different results than `(b>a)?d:c`) and have some difficulties generating branchless code... Note also that aliasing often impact the capacity of GCC to generate vectorized assembly codes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Summary: don't use `#pragma GCC optimize`. Use `-O3` on the command line instead, and you'll get the behavior you expect.**

GCC's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas) on `#pragma GCC optimize` says:

> Each function that is defined after this point is treated as if it had been declared with one `optimize(string)` attribute for each string argument.

[And the `optimize` attribute is documented as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> The optimize attribute is used to specify that a function is to be compiled with different optimization options than specified on the command line. [...] **The optimize attribute should be used for debugging purposes only. It is not suitable in production code.**  [Emphasis added, thanks Peter Cordes for spotting the last part.]

So, don't use it.

In particular, it looks like specifying `#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")` at the top of your file is not actually equivalent to using `-O3` on the command line.  It turns out that the former doesn't result in `std::min` being inlined, and so the compiler actually does assume that it might modify global memory, such as your `a,b` arrays.  This naturally inhibits vectorization.

A careful reading of the documentation for `__attribute__((optimize))`  makes it look like *each* of the functions `main()` and `std::min()` will be compiled as if with `-O3`.  But that's not the same as compiling the two of them together with `-O3`, as only in the latter case would interprocedural optimizations like inlining be available.

[Here is a very simple example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PcK5cEYMT).  With `#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")` the functions `foo()` and `please_inline_me()` are each optimized, but `please_inline_me()` does not get inlined.  But with `-O3` on the command line, it does.

A guess would be that the `optimize` attribute, and by extension `#pragma GCC optimize`, causes the compiler to treat the function as if its definition were in a separate source file which was being compiled with the specified option.  And indeed, if `std::min()` and `main()` were defined in separate source files, you could compile each one with `-O3` but you wouldn't get inlining.

Arguably the GCC manual should document this more explicitly, though I guess if it's only meant for debugging, it might be fair to assume it's intended for experts who would be familiar with the distinction.

If you really do compile your example with `-O3` on the command line, you get identical (vectorized) assembly for both versions, or at least I did.  (After fixing the backwards comparison: your ternary code is computing max instead of min.)

Comment: Probably `-O0` (explicit or default) is "special".  Even if you manually enable all the optimization options that `-O2` includes (reported in asm comments with `-fverbose-asm`), you still have some debug-mode behaviours, IIRC, like not inlining or even still syncing vars to memory between statements.  Maybe setting O3 via a pragma doesn't fully get it out of debug-mode.

Comment: GCC's manual [also says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-optimize-function-attribute) *The optimize **attribute** should be used for debugging purposes only. It is not suitable in production code.* - I assume that applies to the pragma as well.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Good spot in the manual.  I added this to the answer.